# Hibernate HQL could not locate named parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

```
users = (List<User>) currentSession.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM User as u "
            + " LEFT JOIN FETCH u.tests as p"
            +" WHERE u.registrationDate BETWEEN "
            +"':tenDaysBeforeDate' AND ':currDate' "
            +"ORDER BY u.registrationDate DESC").setParameter("tenDaysBeforeDate", tenDaysBeforeDate).setParameter("currDate", currDate).list();
```

what is missing??? both the parameters i am trying to set are of string type please help...

Answer (score 2):

try removing single quote on your paramater

```
users = (List<User>) currentSession.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM User as u "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.patients as p "
        +"WHERE u.registrationDate BETWEEN "
        +":tenDaysBeforeDate AND :currDate "
        +"ORDER BY u.registrationDate DESC").setParameter("tenDaysBeforeDate", tenDaysBeforeDate).setParameter("currDate", currDate).list();
```

Comment: No,it will give classcastException.

Comment: @Jayesh  I think it returns List<Object[]> not List<User> thats why you getting classCastException. to make sure try debugging it first